# Running Weblogic from JDeveloper and accessibility from remote

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

In JDeveloper 11.1.1.5.0 I can run an application in my machine and I can access that application from a different machine, connected in same network , by using URL like 192.168.XXX.XXX:7010/myapp/. But after upgrading into Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6.0 I lost this feature. I might be needed some configuration to do. So how to run Weblogic from JDeveloper such that localhost(192.168.XXX.XXX) can be viewed from a different machine connected in same network?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. You need to do two things.

At first run the server from JDeveloper. Go to Administrative console: http://your.current.address:7101/console. Login with credential. Choose Servers from the tree of Domain Structure, then click on the server you need to configure and insert your IP in the textbox beside Listen Address. Log out.

Stop the server from JDeveloper.

Go to Application Server Properties from JDeveloper. To get this, go to View->Application Server Navigator. Open the tree Application Servers and right click on the Server you are running and want to configure. In my case it is with name IntegratedWeblogicServer. Choose Properties from the context menu. Go to Configuration Tab. Enter your IP in the Weblogic Hostname field. Press ok.

Run your server again and run your application. Browse for URL http://new.address:7101/AppName from different machine connected in same network.

That's all. :)

Answer (score 2):

> I found the solution. You need to do two things.
>
> At first run the server from JDeveloper. Go to Administrative console:
>   http://your.current.address:7101/console. Login with credential.
>   Choose Servers from the tree of Domain Structure, then click on the
>   server you need to configure and insert your IP in the textbox beside
>   Listen Address. Log out.
>
> Stop the server from JDeveloper.
>
> Go to Application Server Properties from JDeveloper. To get this, go
>   to View->Application Server Navigator. Open the tree Application
>   Servers and right click on the Server you are running and want to
>   configure. In my case it is with name IntegratedWeblogicServer. Choose
>   Properties from the context menu. Go to Configuration Tab. Enter your
>   IP in the Weblogic Hostname field. Press ok.
>
> Run your server again and run your application. Browse for URL
>   http://new.address:7101/AppName from different machine connected in
>   same network.
>
> That's all. :)

I did all of that but I can´t still connect but If I only write the IP on the browser it says: IT WORKS! but not with the whole url, the server is a windows server 2008 R2 64bit, please help

FORGET IT! I FIXED IT: I ADDED A NEW INBOUND RULE(Control panel), ALLOWING THE PORT 7101 AND 7102 ! TCP, THANKS ANYWAYS! HOPE MY info helps